# is Boto.exception.BotoServerError's body always strings? How to test if Boto.exception.BotoServerError 400 bad request body is string?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I am developing unit test to test exception parse for boto.exception.BotoServerError 400 Bad request. I need to make sure error.body is str not bytes. But I have no idea what error looks like? Are they predefined by AWS?

Best,

Answer (score 1):

If you catch `ClientError` then you should be able to do this:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

try:
    ddb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
    ddb.describe_table(TableName='fred')
except ClientError as e:
    rc = e.response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode']

    if rc == 400:
        print("Got 400, as expected")
    else:
        print(f'Expected 400, got {rc}')
```

Comment: Do you know how to trigger a code 400 error so i can test?

Comment: Updated example with a test case (where the DDB table 'fred' does not exist).